# React sexy transition: Animate new text on keypress

Tags: css, reactjs, transition

I'm looking to scroll through a story, but let the user press (space) for the next phrase. I think it could be a beautiful optional intro on a website.

**Already done:** I've managed to scroll through an array of strings as the user presses (space):

CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PbRLdp

React / JS:

```
var strings = ["Hi","it's not easy finding a freelancer, is it?", "referrals don't always come", "you need to know it'll get done", "I get it.", "perhaps we should connect"];
var i = 0;

var hitElement = document.querySelector( '.storylines' );
document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if( e.keyCode == 32 ) {
    addHit();
  }
}

var addHit = function() {
  if ( i+2 <= strings.length) {
  i++
  renderStories();
  }
}

var renderStories = function() {
  hitElement.innerHTML = strings[i];
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="storylines">press (spacebar)</span>
```

**My question:** How can I use React to create a transition between phrases? I'm thinking of translating / fading the current span downwards, and fading the new span in (without translating it).

Comment: Why would you want to use React? Although it is very good in a lot of ways, animations are not an out of the box experience there. Simply use CSS animations (it will also play well with React later on).

Comment: Hi SoonDead - this is mainly because I'm learning React (on CodeSchool), and am taking any opportunity to understand it from different angles.
If someone does post a React solution I'll mark it as the answer, but yomisimie's solution certainly works too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to change your question as little as possible since I'm not that familiar with `reactJS`.

I would do it only by `css`. This will allow you to change what each transition focuses on without too much code added (**opacity** vs. **opacity and placement**).

```js
var strings = ["Hi", "it's not easy finding a freelancer, is it?", "referrals don't always come", "you need to know it'll get done", "I get it.", "perhaps we should connect"];
var i = 0;

var hitElement = document.querySelector('.storylines');
document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    addHit();
  }
}

var addHit = function() {
  if (i + 2 <= strings.length) {
    i++
    renderStories();
  }
}

var renderStories = function() {
  hitElement.classList.remove('enter');
  hitElement.classList.add('hide');
  setTimeout(function() {
    hitElement.innerHTML = strings[i];
    hitElement.classList.remove('hide');
    hitElement.classList.add('enter');
  }, 250);
}
```

```css
.storylines {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: opacity 250ms linear 150ms;
  opacity: 0;
}

.storylines.hide {
  transition: all 250ms linear;
  transform: translateY(15px);
  opacity: 0;
}

.storylines.enter {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<span class="storylines enter">press (spacebar)</span>
```

**NOTICE:** click on `Expand snippet` to not have the spacebar scroll the stackoverflow page :-)

This is the logic flow:

1. The page starts with the `storylines` class **and** the `enter` class.

> This is to have the 1st element already shown.

2. When the change occurs, remove the `enter` class, and add the `hide` class to make the class leave.

> hide will make sure the element disappears and moves down. enter is removed so it won't override the `opacity` of the element.
>
> Also, `hide` contains a different `transition` that will animate **all changes**. This allows the `transform` to also move the element on exit.

3. After a timeout, add the `enter` class **and** remove the `hide` class

> Here, since we remove the `hide` class, the `transition` changes to animate only opacity. So, the element appears in place instead of moving up or down.

**NOTICE** that the enter animation as a **delay** value added, so it won't happen in the same time as the hide animation.

`transition: opacity 250ms linear` **`150ms`**`;`

Also, you can change the animations using css only, which I think is a good separation of roles.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed & clear answer, Thatkookooguy!

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your last function:

```
var renderStories = function() {
  hitElement.style.opacity = 0;
  setTimeout(function(){
    hitElement.innerHTML = strings[i];  
    hitElement.style.opacity = 1;
  }, 600);
}
```

An this in your CSS:

```
.storylines {
  transition: all 0.6s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

The JS timeout should be exactly the transition time for your CSS element.

EDIT: With translate

```
var renderStories = function() {
  hitElement.style.opacity = 0;
  hitElement.style.transform = "translateY(-100%)";
  setTimeout(function(){
    hitElement.innerHTML = strings[i];  
    hitElement.style.opacity = 1;
    hitElement.style.transform = "translateY(0%)";
  }, 600);
}
```

CSS

```
.storylines {
  transition: all 0.6s;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block; /* the element needs to be seen as solid */
}
```

EDIT 2: Changed the location so the new line appears in the same place:

```
var renderStories = function() {
  hitElement.style.opacity = 0;
  hitElement.style.transform = "translateY(-100%)";
  setTimeout(function(){
    hitElement.style.trasition = "opacity 0.3s, transform 0s"
    hitElement.style.transform = "translateY(0%)";
  }, 300);
  setTimeout(function(){
    hitElement.innerHTML = strings[i];  
    hitElement.style.opacity = 1;
    hitElement.style.trasition = "opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s"
 }, 600);
}
```

CSS:

```
.storylines {
  transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block; /* the element needs to be seen as solid */
}
```

If you want it slower make sure that the 600 is the double of 0.3 or 300 with whatever value you're changing.

Comment: That's a beautiful solution yomisimie!
The reason I ended my questions with "(without translating it)" is to separate the two animations, so that other viewers can modify each animation themselves.
Unfortunately, I can't follow your code well enough to separate it myself - would you be so kind as to separate the two animations?

Side note: For my own needs, I'll want the new span to appear in the original location (not -100%), and simply fade in.

Comment: The users can modify the translation if you want, you can customize it but you will need a lengthier function. Separate the opacity and translation in the same function?

Comment: My bad then. Try the last version so the new phrase appears in its place instead of transitioning.

Comment: Bang on yomisimie, that does the trick! Thanks for getting there with me!